# c++ lambda pass around auto parameter type

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

I have a lambda function with an auto parameter, that I'd like to push the parameter into a an STL container (e.g. std::vector)

For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    A(int a, T &&t): _a(a), _t(t){}

    int _a;
    T _t;

    void work()
    {
        _t(this);
    }
};

void test()
{
   A a(3, [](auto a_ptr)
   {
      std::cout << a_ptr->_a << std::endl;
   });

   a.work();
}
```

This example works just fine.

However, if I wanted to save a_ptr for later use inside a vector, I have no idea what to write in the vector template parameter.

I don't think I even could use std::function instead of auto in the lambda's parameter type since I think A's type is a recursive (T is lambda that accept a of T...)

Anyway, this is how I'm thinking of solving it, but was wondering if there's a better solution for it:

```
struct base_a
{
    virtual void work() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct A : public base_a
{
    A(int a, T &&t): _a(a), _t(t){}

    int _a;
    T _t;

    virtual void work() override
    {
        _t(this);
    }
};

void test()
{
    std::vector<base_a *> v;

    A a(3, [&v](auto a_ptr)
    {
        v.push_back(a_ptr);
        std::cout << a_ptr->_a << std::endl;
    });

    a.work();

    for (auto i: v)
    {
        i->work();
    }
}
```

Is there a known design pattern for solving this?

Comment: The vector must have all items of the same type. And lambda has no known type. Use std::tuple instead if it's possible https://godbolt.org/z/Gd9jhe

Comment: You call calling work polymorphically so you will need a vector<base_a> or vector<unique_ptr<base_a>> I would avoid raw pointers especially if you are owning the your item.

Comment: @doron, you're right. In my real code I do use shared pointers. This code is just a simplified example

Answer (score 0):

Convert lambda to std::function without params (capturing params you need).

```
void execute_functions(const std::vector<std::function<void()>>& functions) {
  for (const auto& item : functions) {
    item();
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // declare
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions;

  // populate
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    functions.emplace_back([i](){ // < - capture data to process here
      // do something wth data when will be called
      std::cout << i << "\n";
    });
  }

  // execute somewhere
  execute_functions(functions);
  return 0;
}
```

Example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ys6eP5)

Comment: I can't capture the parameters. The lambda is used as a callback function.
I guess it wasn't clear from the example, but in my real application the lambda is forwarded to the invoking class by other classes/methods

Answer (score 0):

I can create a new lambda within the lambda that captures all the parameters and then place it into a vector:

```
void test()
{
    std::vector<std::function <void ()>> v;

    A a(3, [&v](auto a_ptr)
    {
        v.push_back([a_ptr](){
            std::cout << a_ptr->_a << std::endl;
        });
    });

    a.work();

    for (auto &i: v)
    {
        i();
    }
}
```

But I think from a user's perspective (the guy who wrote the test() function), the inheritance method is easier since there maybe multiple lambdas He'd like to keep to handle different situations.

This can make the program flow unnecessarily complicated IMO.